# ListView with Rows and Columns

Tags: wpf, listview, rows

I have a ListView in WPF. I have an ObservableCollection as the ItemsSource. I want the items to simply flow from left to right and then onto the next row left to right etc. Image a Windows Explorer in Large Icon mode where you see the folders and files as large icons in a grid.

I am using a third party component that is based on the ListView, so I have to use ListView methods to make this work.

How do I do it?

Update: Here is my code using the answer given:

```
<diag:NodeListView  Name="nodeListViewSources" Width="400" Margin="0,0,0,0" Background="Gray" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionChanged="nodeListView_SelectionChanged">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</diag:NodeListView>
```

The NodeListView is a third party class derived from a ListView. Maybe that is the problem, but I thought it should work the same.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It did not work. Maybe I put something wrong. I will edit my post with my code so you can tell me what I am doing wrong. As far as my answer rate I am not sure what you mean. Most of my questions have been marked with an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change the items' panel to a [WrapPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.wrappanel.aspx).

```
<ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></WrapPanel>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListView.ItemsPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get a hold of the third party component vendor. Turns out I also needed to add the following:

ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"

This along with the WrapPanel worked. Thanks to all...